# PythonのフレームワークBottleを使用するとUnicodeDecodeErrorが出てしまいます。解決策を教えてください。

Tags: python, bottle

webフレームワークのbottleをインストールして、

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/')
def home():
    return "it is not fancy, but it is my home page"

run(host='localhost', port=9999)
```

を実行すると、

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

というエラーが出てしまいます。
調べてみると、socket.pyというスクリプトの

```
def getfqdn(name=''):
    """Get fully qualified domain name from name.

    An empty argument is interpreted as meaning the local host.

    First the hostname returned by gethostbyaddr() is checked, then
    possibly existing aliases. In case no FQDN is available, hostname
    from gethostname() is returned.
    """
    name = name.strip()
    if not name or name == '0.0.0.0':
        name = gethostname()
    try:
        hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
    except error:
        pass
    else:
        aliases.insert(0, hostname)
        for name in aliases:
            if '.' in name:
                break
        else:
            name = hostname
    return name
```

という箇所の

```
try:
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
```

という部分にエラーが出ているようです。
このエラーを出なくするためにはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Unicodeエラーの原因はいろいろあるのでもう少し環境を正確に教えてください。先頭にcoding: utf-8は書いていますか？Pythonのバージョンは？

Comment: つたない質問で申し訳ありません。coding: utf-8は書いています。pythonのバージョンは3.3です。
一番上のコードはpyscripterで作成して保存したものをターミナルで実行しています。

Comment: 上記のコードには、ホスト名は本当に`localhost`という`ASCII`ばかりの文字列でしょうか。また、`run(host='localhost', port=9999)`の代わりに`run()`を試してみるのはどうでしょうか。その場合には、結果は同じですか？

Comment: 0x82ならSJISが絡んでいるような気がする。PyScripterはWindowsアプリだよね。コピペじゃなくて全部手で打ち直したら動くかも。

Comment: @summea
本によると、lolalhostという文字列で間違いありません。run()も試してみましたが、結果は同じでした。

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi
全て手打ちで書いていますが、このようなエラーが出てしまいました。

Comment: import socket; socket.getfqdn()の結果は何を返しますか？
マシン名かネットワーク名に日本語が含まれていますか？

Comment: @termoshtt 「自分の名前（日本語）－PC」という文字列が帰ってきました

Comment: pcの名前をabcだけに変更すれば動きそうですね。

Comment: PCの名前を変更したところ、動きました！ありがとうございました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

マシン名（ホスト名）に日本語を使うのを止めると解決します。
現在のマシン名の確認は

```
import socket;
print(socket.getfqdn())
```

で確認出来ます。

Comment: 現象としてはマシン名がASCIIなら解決のようですが、localhost指定なのに、マシン名が関係するのはちょっと腑に落ちないですね。